# Custom Data Types Compression

Tags: compression

I currently have an application that requires me to send data with the least amount of bits possible. For example, if I am giving a direction in degrees then the range is 0 -359. that means with 9 bits, I have a number 0 - 511 with resolution of 1. There would be a 'waste' of  152 possible outcomes. I could use those possible outcomes for error handling, but am wondering if there is any method that could be used to pack in some more data.

The only other thought I had was I could add a multiplication factor of 359/511 so that I can squeeze in a little more precision.

Edit: Additional information:

1. It should be assumed that not all messages will get through

some field examples:

Direction base(360)
Day base(366)
hour base(24)
minute base(60)

With these three examples the total wasted outcomes is 905.

Comment: Is the input integer or floating-point to start with? Do you care more about being lossless or about using as few bits as possible? Are consecutive readings likely to be similar (or are related in some other way)?

Comment: I think you are getting at using delta's? That would considerably bring down the size of messages, but you would have to assume a lossy line where not all messages get through.

Comment: What I am really getting at is that we need more information in order to provide meaningful suggestions.

Comment: I doubt that half-bit of wasted space would really make a difference - the inefficiency of protocols these days are shocking (XML is a prime example), so you should be miles ahead of the pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one number you clearly can't have less than 9 bits, so you can't do better. But for multiple numbers you can do better. Two things come to mind:

You can transmit multiple numbers at once in base 360. Here is how to encode and three numbers:

```
int encoded = num0 + 360 * num1 + 360 * 360 * num2;
var decoded0 = encoded / 1 % 360;
var decoded1 = encoded / 360 % 360;
var decoded2 = encoded / 360 / 360 % 360;
```

If you were to use a `BigInteger` you could achieve the theoretically optimal encoding this way in the case of infinitely (or practically very many) numbers.

Or, you can use a variant of [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) that supports more than 2 alternatives. With arithmetic encoding you can encode numbers incrementally and extract bits as they become available. You only need constant memory.

If your numbers are not uniformly distributed (say 0 is twice as likely as usual) the arithmetic coder can use that knowledge to save even more bits. Many general-purpose compressors use this technique (LZMA among them).

Comment: If one assumes an uniform distribution on the given intervals, then this is the optimal solution. I've also seen this technique under the "optimal bit packing" name: http://codeplea.com/optimal-bit-packing

Comment: @usr, great idea but what if the I am sending different based data. For example hour(base24), day(base366) etc

Comment: @Richard then you would use a different base than 360 I guess... Would that be possible? An arithmetic code can uses multiple bases btw. You can use base 360 for the first number, base 24 for the 2nd and so on.

Comment: @usr, Thanks very helpful.  Tamás Zahola link shows a solution that is related to what you had suggested with multiple bases.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular example you gave, "Direction base(360) Day base(366) hour base(24) minute base(60)", it turns out that two of those fit very nicely into 55 bits.  (360 x 366 x 24 x 60)<sup>2</sup> is just a smidge less than 2<sup>55</sup>.  So to encode and decode you just use multiplication and division (getting both quotient and remainder) respectively.  This can be done with 64-bit arithmetic, so no big integer routines are required.  Effectively, only 0.001 bits out of the 55 bits are wasted!

So for `direction:day:hour:minute` with the ranges 1..360, 1..366, 1..24, and 0..59, then the sequence `{a:b:c:d, e:f:g:h}` is coded as `(((((((a - 1) * 366 + (b - 1)) * 24 + (c - 1)) * 60 + d)  * 360 + (e - 1)) * 366 + (f - 1)) * 24 + (g - 1)) * 60 + h`.  To decode take the remainder of division by 60 to get `h`.  Take that quotient, and then the remainder of dividing that by 24 to get `g - 1`, and so on.

Then 55-bit sequences can be concatenated as a bit stream, with eight of them fitting in 55 bytes.

Unused 55-bit sequences can be used to terminate the sequence.  E.g. all 1 bits, all 1 bits except the last bit is zero, etc.  Two different terminators can be used to indicate if the second-to-last 55-bit sequence contained one or two of your vectors.

The only way to do better would be to take advantage of non-uniform distributions on the numbers, and/or correlations between successive vectors.  For the latter, you should consider if some or all of those numbers are likely to be close or the same as the corresponding numbers in the previous vectors.  If there is such a correlation, then you could send differences instead, and with some compression, greatly reduce the total number of bits needed.